# Footer always stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css, position, footer

Hi i need make my footer stick to the bottom even if the content will be longer.
I tried this way .... but it worked only with no content .. in the page with longer content footer stucked in the half of page. Grateful for any Advice

```
    #footer {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the screen, set all your divs to relative, then add an extra div the same height as the footer (set a height for your footer) between the content and the footer. Then put a margin of negative that height on your content div. Works perfectly I have an example i'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

To make a object stick you need to use `fixed` positioning instead of `absolute`

Here is a quick example I made for you,

https://jsfiddle.net/a5juymkm/

**Footer's Code**

```
#Footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; 
    background-color:red;
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: yeah i get it .. but i need footer always in the end of the page not just in the bottom of the screen ...

Comment: @ExDirty haha I mis-read the question, Rachel has a good answer